# Limiting the code to run only when within a specific cell range

Tags: vba, runtime-error

I'm trying to make a Spin Button that will edit the active cell, but only when it is within a specific cell range. I want the code to start up if the active cell is within the range of Sheet 1 cells J63:J97 and, not run if it is outside that range.

This is the code I have so far. It will edit the active cell, as needed. However, it is not limited to the range I need it to be.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)          
  SpinButton1.Value = Selection.Value
End Sub

Private Sub SpinButton1_Change()
  Selection.Value = SpinButton1.Value
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Application.Intersect`. 
I have defined a separate `Function` to do the job.
 
This code is **tested** and it **works**:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If checkIntersection(Target, Range("J63:J97")) Then
        SpinButton1.Value = Selection.Value
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub SpinButton1_Change()
    If checkIntersection(Selection, Range("J63:J97")) Then
        Selection.Value = SpinButton1.Value
    End If
End Sub

'Check if Range1 and Range2 are intersecting
Function checkIntersection(range1 As Range, range2 As Range) As Boolean
    checkIntersection = Not Application.Intersect(range1, range2) Is Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

may check selection with `Intersect`

```
Private Sub SpinButton1_Change()
If Not Intersect(Selection, Range("J63:J97")) Is Nothing Then
Selection.Value = SpinButton1.Value
End If
End Sub
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("J63:J97")) Is Nothing Then
SpinButton1.Value = Selection.Value
End If
End Sub
```